# Output the value of multiple buttons in the console.log

Tags: javascript, html, class, button, console.log

I have multiple HTML buttons with the same `class="preis"`.

```
<button class="preis" value="4,50">4,50€</button>
<button class="preis" value="5,50">5,50€</button>
<button class="preis" value="3,00">3,00€</button>
```

I want to output the value of the exact button I clicked in the console.log. I've tried this so far:

```
function output() {
    console.log(price.value);
}

var price = document.getElementsByClassName("preis");
price.addEventListener("click", output, true);
```

and I want to avoid using different IDs for each button if thats possible.

Comment: you can add a function onClick to each button...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `forEach` with `querySelectorAll`

```js
function output() {
    console.log(this.value);
}

var price = document.querySelectorAll(".preis");
price.forEach(el =>{
  el.addEventListener("click", output, true);
});
```

```html
<button class="preis" value="4,50">4,50€</button>
<button class="preis" value="5,50">5,50€</button>
<button class="preis" value="3,00">3,00€</button>
```

Reference:

-[Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?retiredLocale=en)
-[Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?retiredLocale=en)